# How to I configure lynx user settings without changing OS level settings?

Tags: cookies, lynx

I want to configure lynx to always accept cookies, but without having to hack the OS level configuration in `/etc/lynx.cfg`.

How can I do this? Note: calling `lynx` with command line options is not an acceptable answer, but if you need to setup ENVIRONMENT variables, it's ok, I can put them in `.bashrc`.

Comment: What OS are you using (Linux, I assume)? Why would command line options not be a slution? You could always add an alias to lynx in your .bashrc that includes the options.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in my comment, the easiest way to do this (since according to its `man` page, `lynx` does not have a user configuration file) would be to add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias lynx='lynx -accept_all_cookies'
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc` or just open a new terminal and run `lynx`. Since it is now an alias, you will get the same behavior as if you had explicitly ran `lynx -accept_all_cookies`, but in a way that is completely transparent to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Step one - copy system lynx.cfg:

```
cp /etc/lynx.cfg ~/
```

Step two - modify your ~/lynx.cfg to your heart's content.

Step three - launch lynx with your custom cfg:

```
lynx -cfg=~/lynx.cfg <url>
```

It's possible older versions of lynx did not allow you to specify a config, but you can with my version.

```
lynx --version

Lynx Version 2.8.6rel.5 (09 May 2007)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips, ncurses 5.7.20090207(wide)
Built on linux-gnu Nov 23 2010 12:44:01

Copyrights held by the University of Kansas, CERN, and other contributors.
Distributed under the GNU General Public License.
See http://lynx.isc.org/ and the online help for more information.

See http://www.openssl.org/ for information about OpenSSL.
```

Answer (score 1):

Lynx supports per-user configuration in [`.lynxrc`](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html#InteractiveOptions):

> The Lynx Options Menu may be accessed by pressing the “o” key. It allows you to change options at runtime, if you need to. Most changes are read from & saved to your .lynxrc file; those which are not are marked (!) in the form-based menu (as below). Many other options are stored in the lynx.cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy the system-wide lynx.cfg to your user's home directory and change your desired settings on a per-user level.

Comment: As per this answer http://superuser.com/a/909446/757 you must edit the global config to allow this

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is old but I ended up here and there is no correct answer, I read the manual and found that you can add the following to your `/etc/lynx.cfg` to allow explicit options to be source from a dot file in your home dir.

```
INCLUDE:~/.lynx.cfg for PERSISTENT_COOKIES COOKIE_FILE
```

The following description take straight from the config file explains it better that I could

```
# Starting with Lynx 2.8.2, the INCLUDE facility is yet more powerful.  You can
# suppress all but specific settings that will be read from included files.
# This allows sysadmins to provide users the ability to customize lynx with
# options that normally do not affect security, such as COLOR, VIEWER, KEYMAP.
#
# The syntax is
#
#   INCLUDE:filename for <space-separated-list-of-allowed-settings>
#
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this old and many have already provided valid answers but I thought this might help someone..

In case you're in rush and would like to add few configuration (`CHARACTER_SET:UNICODE (UTF-8)` in my case) here's a quick solution

`lynx -cfg=<(echo 'CHARACTER_SET:UNICODE (UTF-8)') ...`

or if you're in fish

`lynx -cfg=(echo 'CHARACTER_SET:UNICODE (UTF-8)' | psub) ...`

replacing `'CHARACTER_SET:UNICODE (UTF-8)'` with your config