# Can I configure lynx to show me hidden files when browsing a directory?

Tags: lynx

Can I configure lynx to show me files/folders starting with dot when browsing a local directory? For example:

```
.git
.bashrc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>o</kbd> (for options)
2. Change `Show dot files` to `on`
3. `Accept Changes`
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (to refresh)

Comment: Hi @john mee, I can't find the 'Show dot files' options. What version of lynx are you using? I am using Lynx Version 2.8.8rel.2 (09 Mar 2014) on mac os 10.13.6

Comment: Update: Kasapo's answer at https://superuser.com/questions/518431/how-to-i-configure-lynx-user-settings-without-changing-os-level-settings worked for me.

Comment: "Show dot files" was added to the options menu in 2.8.1 (about 20 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Copy system-wide lynx.cfg to home directory

```
cp /usr/local/etc/lynx.cfg ~
```

Edit ~/lynx.cfg. Change

```
#NO_DOT_FILES:TRUE
```

to
    NO_DOT_FILES:FALSE

and change

```
#ENABLE_LYNXRC:SHOW_DOTFILES:ON
```

to

```
ENABLE_LYNXRC:SHOW_DOTFILES:ON
```

Save your lynx.cfg

Open lynx as follows:

```
lynx -cfg ~/lynx.cfg .
```